# Was L suspicious of all Light's girlfriends or only Misa?

Tags: death-note

In Death Note, Chapter 33 (Vol. 4), Misa Amane is arrested under the suspicion she was the Second Kira. After that, L said that they collected lots of evidences in Misa's room (the cat hair found on the video cassette, make-up powder, clothing fibers etc.), besides the fact the criminal who killed her parents was killed by Kira. Supposedly, the objects L was analysing in Chapter 32 (a hair, crumbs from a snack) were collected from her room.

However, how L became suspicious of Misa before seeing her in Chapter 32, in Light's university? I suppose he discovered the relationship between Light and Misa because Mogi saw when the girl appeared suddenly to Light in Chapter 31, and so L ordered an inspection to her room. So, is there any indication that he was him investigating every one of the Light's "girfriends" (including the "Refined Takada"), or it was just Misa that caught the attention of the detective?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like it could've just been the way Misa acted toward's Light... That and the fact that she was a very popular model talking to a regular student. He could've seen how bubbly her personality is and how much she doesnt fit into Light's "no nonsense" studios type of personality. If you can tell he doesnt really want to be around her then it wouldnt be a far reach to assume that she's around for some other reason.

Comment: Maybe, but I think it's possible that L, being L, investigated every one of them 
I was a bit suspicious of a plothole because of how fast L's team went from seeing Misa with Light to having the proofs that Misa send the Second Kira videos (hair, the objects etc.).

Well, maybe that is a question that the authors never addressed

Answer (score 0):

first of all there were no girlfriend of Light in whole series, he just pretended Misa Amane and other girl to be his girlfriend. But in actual there is no girlfriend of Light in whole series. and about being suspicious by L, Missa Amane was the only girl who had been suspected as Second Kira upto some extent. L just torture her to get the information about the Shinigami and Deathnote but somehow Missa Amane was fully mentally prepared for that as she had been suggested by Light. So Misa Amane was only girl who had suspected for being Second Kira.

Comment: "girlfriends" is a manner of speaking... anyway, the question is not about L being suspicious of the other girls being the Second Kira, just if he investigates them as he did with Misa